# Ruby IDE for Ubuntu

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

I am in search of a light-weight RoR IDE for Ubuntu. Netbeans is good but bulky for a beginner. Same is true with Eclipse.

Is there any simple IDE which is also FREE?

Comment: Some options are given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer. I will say nothing is lighter than VIM. Chk out http://biodegradablegeek.com/2007/12/using-vim-as-a-complete-ruby-on-rails-ide/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Eclipse plugin [RadRails](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Installing_RadRails_on_Ubuntu_Linux) is available for Ubuntu.

Edit: If that is not to your taste, [here are several others](http://tips.webdesign10.com/editors-for-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-jedit-emacs-radrails-cream-scite)

Answer (score 0):

[rails.vim](http://rails.vim.tpope.net/) provides a very convenient environment for working with Rails projects in Vim, just watch [the screencast](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2139263225227275468). However, I wouldn't recommend it to a beginner who's never used Vim. It's better to focus on learning one thing at a time.