# Developer studio for ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, programming, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

is there any developer tool that is released by canonical for ubuntu like the visual studio  for windows which is released by microsoft. if no which is the best GUI application development tool for ubuntu.

Comment: You might be interested in checking out a similar question ask on StackOverflow, and specifically the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux/24119#24119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what do you expect from "developer studio". Almost every text editor supports some features such as syntax highliting, try gedit.

Many developers still prefer working in command line with vim editor. It's very powerful, but it has (for today) unusual control mechanisms (3 modes, etc.). See http://www.vim.org/

If you prefer more powerful IDE, there are 2 options included in the Ubuntu packages by default. However, noone of them is installed out of the box. You can get NetBeans and Eclipse by simple:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Both of them are based on java so you need java to run them (java is installed by default so you don't need to bother with this). I have very good experience with NetBeans, it supports many programming languages, enterprise features, versioning etc. Check it out on http://netbeans.org. However, usually there is not the latest version in the packages so you can download it from the webpage. It works perfectly for me, except updates, so I need to update manually.

I don't have any experience with eclipse but it's said to be even better than NetBeans. Especially, it supports many SDKs or addons for special development like Android or Windows Azure.

The third option of IDEs I'd offer to you is IntelliJ IDEA. As far as I know, it's not present in packages, but you can download it on the official webpage: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/. There is many versions of JetBrains IDEs, supporting different languages and providing different options. Some of them are free, some of them are paid.

Of course, there is a LOT of more options. Depends what language are you willing to use, what services you need to connect to etc.