# A great Python IDE for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, python, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

I want to **develop Python apps in Ubuntu**, and I'm tired of working with **gedit** one time and another.

So I'm trying to find a great Python IDE (a *true* IDE, not just a syntax-highlighting editor) on the Ubuntu repositories. **Which one do you recommend me?**