# How do I enable syntax highlighting in nano?

Tags: nano, syntax-highlighting

Can nano do syntax highlighting like gedit and vim? How can I enable it? I need at least bash and python syntax highlights.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

The nano editor provides syntax highlighting for a few languages and scripts by itself. Check out `/usr/share/nano/`

```
nits@nits-excalibur:~$ ls /usr/share/nano/
asm.nanorc     fortran.nanorc   man.nanorc     ocaml.nanorc   ruby.nanorc
awk.nanorc     gentoo.nanorc    mgp.nanorc     patch.nanorc   sh.nanorc
c.nanorc       groff.nanorc     mutt.nanorc    perl.nanorc    tcl.nanorc
cmake.nanorc   html.nanorc      nano-menu.xpm  php.nanorc     tex.nanorc
css.nanorc     java.nanorc      nanorc.nanorc  pov.nanorc     xml.nanorc
debian.nanorc  makefile.nanorc  objc.nanorc    python.nanorc
```

Link them to your user's nano configuration file (present at `~/.nanorc`, `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nano/nanorc`, or `~/.config/nano/nanorc`, whichever is encountered first) with something similiar to this line:

```
nits@nits-excalibur:~$ cat ~/.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/sh.nanorc
```

Now, syntax highlighting is enabled in nano for whatever file you linked (You could also link multiple files)

[image: screenshot of syntax highlighting]

Note: Sometimes you might get a `segmentation fault` after you have edited your `~/.nanorc` file. If such an error occurs, unsetting the  *LANG* environment variable helps. You can unset it with `unset LANG` in the terminal. (Solution obtained from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10585542&postcount=3))

There are also other solutions if you are not satisfied with your bash highlighting. One example of such can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120505142950/http://www.criticalsecurity.net/index.php/topic/32987-proper-bash-scripting-syntax-highlighting-in-nano)

You can also write `include /usr/share/nano/*` to the ~/.nanorc file to enable all languages to be highlighted if your nano version supports it.

Comment: Those lines are uncommented in `/etc/nanorc` - are the global settings being overwritten by `~/.nanorc`? How do I disable `.nanorc`?

Comment: Oh wait, I don't even have a `~/.nanorc` file.

Comment: The global settings (in `/etc`) provide settings for all users. The `~/.nanorc` provides additional settings for your user-profile. To disable your '~/.nanorc' you can just rename it or delete it. (Edit after the second comment), you can create one by `touch ~/.nanorc`

Comment: Wait, wait, how come the global setting with all the `include` lines not enabling syntax highlights even though I have not `.nanorc`?

Comment: This is an excerpt from the `/etc/nanorc` - `## Please note that you must have configured nano with --enable-nanorc
 for this file to be read! `

Comment: Ah, I did not read it properly. I see now, thanks. So either I have a `.nanorc` file or I modify `.bashrc` to add `--enable-nanorc` flag whenever I type nano... And I was hoping that I would be able to do away with user-specific changes... Anyway, thanks for all the help.

Comment: How do you do it while inside nano?

Comment: To enable syntax highlighting when editing a file with an unrecognised filename extension (such as `~/.bashrc`), you can use the `--syntax` option. For example: `nano --syntax=sh ~/.bashrc`

Comment: `ls -1 /usr/share/nano/*.nanorc | sed 's/^\//include \//' >> ~/.nanorc` append them all to your .nanorc file, or create it if it does not exist.

Comment: ```include /usr/share/nano/*``` is not working

Comment: Even I didn't have a ~/.nanorc file, but I just created one using nano itself. I can't believe this stuff isn't enabled by default!

Comment: If I write `include /usr/share/nano/*` to ~/.nanorc, I just get `Error reading /usr/share/nano/*: No such file or directory` on starting nano.  Could I be doing something wrong, or should that bit be removed from the answer?

Comment: @mwfearnley It should probably be removed. Fileglob is not supported throughout all versions of nano.

Comment: @JarekJakubowski use `include "/usr/share/nano/*.nanorc"` I think it needs double quotes

Comment: In my case there was a directory `/usr/share/nano/extra`, so `nano` printed error `[ Mistakes in '/home/sunnycove/.config/nano/nanorc' ]`, if `include /usr/share/nano/*` set. Fixed with `include /usr/share/nano/*.nanorc`

Answer (score 105):

Yes you can, however the default syntax definitions are quite poor and incomplete. I'm maintaining a more accurate set of definitions [here](https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc), for anyone who finds them useful.

To install, run:

```
git clone https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc.git
cd nanorc
make install
```

Add these lines to the ~/.nanorc

```
include ~/.nano/syntax/html.nanorc
include ~/.nano/syntax/css.nanorc
include ~/.nano/syntax/php.nanorc
include ~/.nano/syntax/ALL.nanorc
```

Specify the ones you want to have colorizing for, and you will have to tune these colors to your preferences.  The `ALL.nanorc` describes features for all yet unclassified files.  These are the tools you need to get started, not the end polished product.

Comment: My *.js files weren't working...edited /etc/nanorc to remove any other syntax includes as per the FAQ https://github.com/nanorc/nanorc#why-does-syntax-highlighting-only-work-for-a-subset-of-supported-files. ♥ Nano ♥ nanorc

Comment: I just installed your syntax defs on Mac OSX. There's only one thing I'd note, which is the black colour of the open-bracket in python gets lost against the black background of my terminal

Comment: Actually there is a problem, some of the colored text is black! If our terminal background is black, these words are invisible!

Comment: thanks for your hard work! you should get this into the [upstream repo](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nano), IMHO

Comment: +druciferre provides a great command below that adds all syntax files automatically to your .nanorc file. I changed the path to point to your default install location: `find $HOME/.nano/syntax/ -iname "*.nanorc" -exec echo include {} \; >> ~/.nanorc`

Comment: On FreeBSD with nano 2.4.3, with or without BSDREGEX=1, I get error message `make: "/usr/home/freebsd/nanorc/Makefile" line 40: Missing dependency operator
make: "/usr/home/freebsd/nanorc/Makefile" line 42: Need an operator
...(skipping similar lines)...make: Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue
make: stopped in /usr/home/freebsd/nanorc`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Same procedure with all syntax files at once: `find $HOME/.nano/syntax/ -iname "*.nanorc" -exec echo include {} \; >> ~/.nanorc`. Also, since all syntax files are now on `$HOME/.nano/syntax/` is safe to delete the cloned folder.

Comment: In alpine virtual x86_64.I cloned git and created .nanorc in root directory which has include "./nanorc/*.nanorc" and everything worked perfectly. No need to make install or install.sh if I am not missing something huge ...

Answer (score 75):

I used this command to quickly enable all available languages.

```
find /usr/share/nano/ -iname "*.nanorc" -exec echo include {} \; >> ~/.nanorc
```

As mentioned in other answers, `/usr/share/nano/` contains the definitions for different languages.

```
$ ls /usr/share/nano
asm.nanorc     fortran.nanorc   man-html       ocaml.nanorc   ruby.nanorc
awk.nanorc     gentoo.nanorc    man.nanorc     patch.nanorc   sh.nanorc
cmake.nanorc   groff.nanorc     mgp.nanorc     perl.nanorc    tcl.nanorc
c.nanorc       html.nanorc      mutt.nanorc    php.nanorc     tex.nanorc
css.nanorc     java.nanorc      nanorc.nanorc  pov.nanorc     xml.nanorc
debian.nanorc  makefile.nanorc  objc.nanorc    python.nanorc
```

Also mentioned, to enable highlighting for a language, you add `include` and the path to the language definition you want to enable to your `~/.nanorc` file. So, for example, to enable C/C++ you would add this line.

```
include /usr/share/nano/c.nanorc
```

The `find` command searches for files or directories within the specified directory.

- The `-iname` flag tells it to only look for files with a name that ends with `.nanorc`.
- The `-exec` flags defines a command to execute on each file found.
- The `{}` gets replaced with the file name.
- `\;` is used to signify the end of the command  to execute to the `find` command.
- Lastly, `>> ~/.nanorc` causes the output to be appended to your `~/.nanorc` file.

Comment: great tip and explanation, thanks a lot man! ;)

Comment: Thanks and doesn't look like you need the iname flag.  The following seems to work as well
find /usr/share/nano/*.nanorc

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but I just added this to my puppet configuration and would make one small addition, adding sort before appending to the file.  find /usr/share/nano/ -iname "*.nanorc" -exec echo include {} \; || sort >> ~/.nanorc this will make it easier to see if you have language support or not when adding a new language.

Answer (score 8):

This should include all the syntax highlighting plugins included by default, and any you add to /usr/share/nano:

```
find /usr/share/nano -name '*.nanorc' -printf "include %p\n" > ~/.nanorc
```

Or, edit /etc/nanorc and see if you can uncomment the includes.

This works if you have a version of nano that refuses to accept wildcards in the .nanorc file.

Just run this line every time you add an additional .nanorc colour config.

Comment: IMHO that's not a good solution, because this eliminates all the settings from the users current `.nanorc` by overwriting it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this to include all: (add this to `~/.nanorc` file)

```
include "/usr/share/nano/*.nanorc"
```

Happy coding!

Comment: this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 5):

I accidentally disabled highlighting using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. It can be turned on again with the same keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I might suggest something more fresh and up-to-date as of almost 2020 :

[Scopatz's nanorc](https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc)  on Git has all you need. it is still regularly updated.

and is delivered with a pretty neat install guide & documented installer that allows you to get things rolling fast, clean, & easy.

Note : You might have to drop some of the highlighters from the nanorc file or comment them out (etc-host, html, and html.j2) as they seem to be faulty, but no big deal

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: outdated, please refer to other answers**

The most complete and up to date syntax hilighters for nano are maintained [here](https://github.com/tech4david/nano-highlight)

To install all highlighters for your user just run:

```bash
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/tech4david/nano-highlight.git
cd nano-highlight/
make install
echo "include ~/.nano/syntax/ALL.nanorc" >> ~/.nanorc
```

Comment: The solution is good, but I would use an other folder for `git clone`. The content otf the `/tmp` folder will be deleted on every system start and therefore you could never run a `git pull`.

Comment: Your language tag is wrong. `js` isn't `bash` or `shell-script` and I have placed the link behind the word `here`. Where is the problem?

Comment: @A.B. it doesn't matter if that folder is gone since when you `make install` all the syntax files are copied to the safe place where they belong: `~/.nano/syntax`.

Comment: Project is now archived. Not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are having trouble after following the instructions above, also check if you have **duplicate definitions**. These will disable *all syntax highlighting* for *all files*. I ran into this after adding a `nanorc.nanorc` file, and not realising that my `~/.nanorc` already had an identical section, i.e.:

```
## Here is an example for nanorc files.
##
syntax "nanorc" "\.?nanorc$"
## Possible errors and parameters
icolor brightwhite "^[[:space:]]*((un)?set|include|syntax|i?color).*$"
## Keywords
icolor brightgreen "^[[:space:]]*(set|unset)[[:space:]]+(autoindent|backup|$
icolor green "^[[:space:]]*(set|unset|include|syntax)\>"
(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old thread but may my solution can help

edit the file at /etc/nanorc

From the line 243 you can find lot include files. Simply uncomment the ones you need, save and done.

```
## Nanorc files
include "/usr/share/nano/nanorc.nanorc"

## C/C++
include "/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc"

## Makefiles
include "/usr/share/nano/makefile.nanorc"

## Cascading Style Sheets
include "/usr/share/nano/css.nanorc"

## Debian files
include "/usr/share/nano/debian.nanorc"

## Gentoo files
# include "/usr/share/nano/gentoo.nanorc"
```

I am not sure if you update nano will these changes vanished.

Answer (score 1):

nano ~/.nanorc

just write below code i

```
include "/usr/share/nano/*.nanorc"

set linenumbers
```

Answer (score 1):

To add support for TypeScript JSX (.tsx) files do the following:

1. Open ~/.nanorc file and find "javascript" slug using ctrl+w in nano editor
2. You should find something like `include /Users/youruser/nanorc/javascript.nanorc`, open this .nanorc file
3. On the first line edit `syntax "JavaScript" "\.(js|ts)$"` to `syntax "JavaScript" "\.(js|ts|jsx|tsx)$"` to include .jsx and .tsx file extensions

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=3 --no-parent --reject="index.html*" https://nanosyntax.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/syntax-nanorc/ -P ~/.nano-syntax
for i in `ls --color=never -1 ~/.nano-syntax/*.nanorc` ; do echo "include $i" >> ~/.nanorc ; done
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why this is a useful answer for newer users. What is the command doing? What does it change? Randomly suggesting to run a command line is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found syntax highlighting for js [here](https://code.google.com/p/nanosyntax/source/browse/trunk/syntax-nanorc/js.nanorc).

I appended it into my user file at `~/.nanorc`

However to get a file into which I could append, I had to first copy from `/usr/share/nano/nanorc.nanorc` to my local folder first as `~/.nanorc`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have working and included `*.nanorc` files but still see a monochrome text (or maybe regular and bold, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> while editing to toggle syntax highlighting), it may be your TERM environment variable is not recognized. I had it set to `xterm-256color` but on that particular host that value didn't use color in nano for whatever reason.. doing `$ TERM=screen` worked for me.
You can see what it currently is with `$ echo $TERM`.