# Syntax highlighting with less, trouble with lexer

Tags: command-line, bash, syntax-highlighting, less

I have installed `python-pygments` and using it for syntax highlighting with `less` as described by mankoff [here](https://superuser.com/questions/71588/how-to-syntax-highlight-via-less)
I put a function in my `.bashrc`

```bash
cless () {
    pygmentize -f terminal "$1" | less -R
}
```

it is enabling syntax highlighting with `less`. But when I am going to open a file like `/etc/fstab` or `/etc/apt/apt.conf` a error saying

```
Error: no lexer for filename '/etc/apt/apt.conf' found
```

I found option to show `pygmentize` the lexer with `-l` at this [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pygmentize.1.html). But what will be the appropriate lexer for such files? and how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buried in `pygmentize --help`:

> If -g is passed,
>   attempt to guess the lexer from the file contents, or pass through as
>   plain text if this fails (this can work for stdin).

Simply change your code to:

```
cless () {
    pygmentize -gf terminal "$1" | less -R
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have syntax highlight on Ubuntu/Debian first install

```
apt install source-highlight
```

Then you may want to add this two environment variables to `~/.bashrc`

```conf
export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"
export LESS=' -R '
```

**Tip**: Also notice <kbd>v</kbd> on `less` open the file on default editor ([defined by `select-editor` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73484/how-can-i-set-vi-as-my-default-editor-in-unix)) that maybe have syntax highlight. [Here it is how to add](https://askubuntu.com/a/90026/349837) compatibility to a lot of file types in `nano`.

#### Reference

- [gnu.org - 2.7 Using source-highlight with less](https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html#Using-source_002dhighlight-with-less)
- [bash - less command and syntax highlighting - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73484/how-can-i-set-vi-as-my-default-editor-in-unix)
- [How to syntax highlight via Less - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/71588/how-to-syntax-highlight-via-less)