# How can I enable syntax highlighting in a Python file without an extension?

Tags: python, nano

[Turning on syntax highlighting in Nano](https://askubuntu.com/q/90013/449) is simple enough but I've just run into a non-standard issue. I have an executable Python script that doesn't have an extension.

It's part of a virtualenv environment so here's how it starts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can select a specific syntax highlighting using the `--syntax` option, for example

```
nano --syntax=python myscript
```

Comment: perfect and simple

Answer (score 2):

Nano's default Python definition looks for one of two things an extension or a header match, as defined in `/usr/share/nano/python.nanorc`:

```
syntax "python" "\.py$"
header "^#!.*/python[-0-9._]*"
```

So this would match `#!/bin/python`. Unless you're writing something for the system, hard-coding the Python executable is a fairly bad idea... That's why `env python` is used these days.

The most simple way to fix Nano is to edit the definition by running `sudoedit /usr/share/nano/python.nanorc` and changing the `header` line to:

```
header "^#!.*python.*"
```

That is a *lot* more open.

---

There's actually a massively improved set of Syntax files available at [the nanorc project](https://github.com/nanorc/nanorc) on Github, that as well as improving other things, specifies:

```
header "^#!.*/(env +)?python[-0-9._]*( |$)"
```

It's no longer maintained but it's still a massive improvement over the defaults. It's fairly simple to install:

```
git clone https://github.com/nanorc/nanorc.git
cd nanorc
make install
```

Then `nano ~/.nanorc` and add:

```
include ~/.nano/syntax/ALL.nanorc
```