# What editor can I use as a simple vi/vim alternative?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, text-editor, vi

I'm a Windows user coming to Ubuntu's Bash thanks to [WSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/). Now I need to edit some files and I really hate Vi. Do I just have to deal with it, or is there a simpler alternative?

The features I am looking for are:

- CLI based
- easy to use (typing and editing should be similar to Notepad)
- simple editing capabilities are enough

I will try to master Vim, but I need to make a quick edit right now!

Comment: It is a matter of opinion. Beginners use nano https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/ . vim (vi improved) has a bit of a learning curve but it is very powerful - See https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-101-beginners-guide-vim or any vim guides or the vim tutorial , vimtutor (included in vim)

Comment: Please note that this question might be closed as quite opinion-based. You might want to reword it to fit the rules of the site (e.g. what can I use as alternative to vim?)

Comment: Voting to close this as opinion-based question. Word of advice: start with nano, and later transition to vim with baby-steps. It will pay off in long run because vim is on any Linux system basically

Comment: As a follow up to my comment, the current title is still debatable and could lead to closing. People might consider vim itself to be "good", and this is subjective. May I suggest using the word "easier" instead? Also specifying some desired features could help in narrowing down the question.

Comment: Please note that these answers (vi, nano) address terminal editors only. While knowledge of these is extremely useful, in practice you would more often use a GUI-based editor like Geany, Gedit, Atom, Sublime Text and many more.

Comment: `mcedit` (part of `mc`). If I need anything else, it usually means I don't need a text editor but either a text processor or an IDE. There's a lot of console-based editors out in the wild (`pico`, `nano`, `vi`, `vim`, `ed`, `emacs`, `joe` ... the list goes on), but there was only one editor I didn't need to memorize at all - and that's `mcedit` (based on `cooledit` btw).

Comment: @Jos we are talking about WSL where running GUI programs can be done but is not trivial. Also the question wouldn't exists for GUI editors because they are all easier than vim.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I interpreted "coming to Ubuntu thanks to WSL" as "I have switched from Windows to Ubuntu". I may be wrong, of course.

Comment: @Jos OP wrote “coming to Ubuntu's bash”. :) Your comments contains very good suggestion, I just don't think they are essential to be mentioned because basically all GUI editors have a sane interface, which instead is not always found in CLI tools (e.g. vim).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto is right, but thanks for the suggestions Jos

Comment: I reworded the question to fit the format of this site. I tried to keep it as close as possible to your original goal while clarifying some features that are needed for the tool you are looking for. Please [edit] the question further if I inadvertently changed some of your requirements. See the guidelines here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14399/271

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy What you offer could be good advice, but I would also suggest trying to go "full vim" for one week. It really only takes learning `ciw` `diw` `yiw` and a few movement commands to really understand what vim is trying to do. Baby steps might work for some, but in my case (and many other anecdotal cases) going into the deep end for a week worked out better than the one-step-at-a-time approach because as a noob I would be tempted to resort to 'jjjjjjjjjjjhhhhhh' every time I switched back from a "dumb" editor. It's akin to learning Morse Code at 18 wpm (good) vs 5 (bad habits).

Comment: The reason Vim pays off is not so much as you find it everywhere as because there is no other editor on the planet to beat it. You find that in the end you'll want to install Vim anywhere where it isn't there already.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you are looking for an alternative editor, you are not alone. Basically *life is too short* to learn `vi` and I say this being a software developer for a living. However you *should* learn how to exit it because it's a problem for [one out of 20k programmers](https://web.archive.org/web/20170614081125/https://medium.freecodecamp.com/one-out-of-every-20-000-stack-overflow-visitors-is-just-trying-to-exit-vim-5a6b6175e7b6). Also performing some basic append/insert operation might be worth learning, because on some stubborn servers you won't find any other editor.

Now, the answer to your question is probably `nano`.

If you are running some automated build script, using `git` or running other commands, they might open `vim` without you wanting it. You can prevent this by running the following before proceeding:

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

Comment: "Basically life is too short to learn vi". No need to spend entire life, although one can if they love vim. I spent 2 hours watching a good tutorial on YouTube,  and just kept practicing basics that I learned from the video. Now 70% of all my answers on Ask Ubuntu are written in vim.

Comment: On "life is too short", I thought [this essay](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/07/29/everyone-who-tried-to-convince-me-to-use-vim-was-wrong/) had a good point. One of the biggest (artificial) roadblocks in learning Vim is the false premise that you need to immediately dive into becoming a "hard core" user. You don't. Use the arrow keys. Use the GUI shortcuts to copy/paste. Hang out in insert mode. Ignore tabs and registers and bells and whistles (for now). It's relatively quick to get to nano-level functionality in Vim, and you can slowly add advanced features later, as you need them.

Comment: @R.M. GUI shortcuts?

Comment: @Sergiy vim makes sense if you want to use advanced features. If I were to use vim like I use nano I would just keep using nano (as a matter of fact, I do... I use vim when I am on a server on which I cannot add software, like a client's machine).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Exactly ! If you can use what you like - sure. That's not always the case of course, and `vim` makes sense if you're working with variety of *nix systems, legacy systems, client's servers, etc.  My main point was that `vim`  isn't being taught properly, and people focus on the "so many features" part, which leads people to mistakenly believe it's hard to learn. It's not, because 80% of the time what a person needs to do in vim is only 20% or less of what it can do.  And I absolutely agree with what R.M. said

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy what I wanted to say is that you should not be required to *learn* how to do basic operations like typing a word, a newline or exiting the program. Something like the message in this picture, I guess: https://twitter.com/p_redaelli/status/868385233556480000 I use CLI tools all day long, but I'm not a guy who tries to use a textual editor like it were an IDE. If I need an IDE, I open an IDE. For the rest, `nano` is enough for me and for 99% of users. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I agree that it shouldn't be hard to learn how to do such basic things. That said: typing a word: press `i`, then type the word(s), then press `ESC`. Newline: press `ENTER`. Exit: type `:q`. Now that you know the basics, you can gradually pick up the more powerful features. A few minutes of learning will let you use vim to do everything you can do in nano, plus a few extra things. After that, it just becomes even more useful every time you pick up a new trick. After awhile, it'll also become (far) more useful than an IDE. But you can still use it normally before you get there

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto By GUI shortcuts I mean things like ctrl-C/ctrl-V, or ctrl-shift-C/ctrl-shift-V or cmd-C/cmd-V or highlight/middle-click. (They're different depending on OS and interface to Vim/terminal you use, so I didn't want to specify.)  -- The point is they're not the "official" Vim way to do it, but they still work.

Comment: @Ray thanks, I already know how to do those things using its absurd interface, and I'm WAY less productive than when I use nano. I guess you didn't check the picture I linked though. :)

Comment: @R.M. if I have access to a GUI then I can open Atom to get a useful text editor with syntax highlighting, multiple cursors, auto-completion, multiple tabs/panels  and other stuff. The only reason one is forced to use vim is when needing some advanced features and there is no GUI (assuming you remember 30 different keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: My first several months of `vi` use were just `i`, normie text editing, then `Esc`, `:q` or `:wq`, and `Enter`. If you're happy with a normie text editor, insert mode in `vi` *is* a normie editor so long as your terminal lets you select text and copy+paste. Then if/when you start to want to do something faster, you can just incrementally learn commands to do that.

Answer (score 16):

It is a matter of opinion.

Beginners use [nano](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/).

vim ("vi improved") has a bit of a learning curve but it is very powerful. See [this beginner's guide for vim](https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-101-beginners-guide-vim) or any other vim guides or the vim tutorial `vimtutor` (included in vim).

For now I highly suggest nano

```
nano -B /path/to/file/to/edit
```

-B makes a backup

Commands are issued with the control key and are listed at the bottom of the editor window.

There' a a guide on syntax highlighting see: [How do I enable syntax highlighting in nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90013/how-do-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-nano)

[image: nano]

`emacs` is an alternate to both `vim` and `nano` and has many benefits as well. `emacs` is more complex than nano. You can see [emac's tour](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/).

Just for completeness, vim + themes such as Zenburn can be quite helpful

[image: Zenburn]

Comment: Not only beginners, basically all humans that do not want to enter the vim vs emacs wars. :P

Comment: Well, to be fair, you can theme vim and a .vimrc goes a long ways. vim and emacs have advanced features that are not available in nano, but it is a waste if you do not use the advanced features. For quick basic edits I use nano although overall I am a vim fanboi. http://kippura.org/zenburnpage/

Comment: Up vote for `-B` :D

Comment: Learn `vi/vim`. :) It is on every nix device. :) Basics aren't that hard.

Comment: "emacs is more complex than nano." :p this could be the understatement of the year.

Comment: @DanielJour by a few lines of source code yea :P

Comment: I honestly don't understand why people say "vim is very powerful," other than _that's what vim says about itself_ in the first line of vimtutor. Anything I can do in vim I can with VS Code or what have you, and with far fewer keystrokes.

Comment: a quick summary of the shortcuts one may need most when using __nano__: comment multiple lines: `esc+3`, delete multiple lines: `ctrl+k`(it basically cuts those lines but there's no difference if you don't paste them afterwards) ;-) , paste lines: `ctrl+u`("u" stands for "uncut"), to search for something: `ctrl+w` then type the name and enter, to go to a specific line number: `ctrl+shift+w`, to cancel anything: `ctrl+c`, to save: `ctrl+o`, to save & exit: `ctrl+x`, to undo: `alt+U`, to redo: `alt+E`.

Comment: Cat.  It's on every unix machine.  Works for me.

Answer (score 8):

as a windows power user, after trying `vim` and `nano` I found out that I need something in between, complexity-wise.
so I tried [slap](https://github.com/slap-editor/slap) and It was **the exact thing** that I was looking for.

### [image: slap image]

> slap is a Sublime-like terminal-based text editor that strives to make
> editing from the terminal easier.
> slap has first-class mouse support, even over SSH connection.

---

installation:

```
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slap-editor/slap/master/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the main selling point, **first-class mouse support (even over an SSH connection)**

Answer (score 6):

[`Tilde`](https://github.com/gphalkes/tilde) is **exactly** what you're looking for.

To quote from [Tilde's homepage](https://os.ghalkes.nl/tilde)

> Tilde is a text editor for the console/terminal, which provides an intuitive interface for people accustomed to GUI environments such as Gnome, KDE and Windows. For example, the short-cut to copy the current selection is Control-C, and to paste the previously copied text the short-cut Control-V can be used. As another example, the File menu can be accessed by pressing Meta-F.

If you're used to keyboard shortcuts like

- `Ctrl + C` for copy,
- `Ctrl + V` for paste,
- `Ctrl + A` for select all,
- `Ctrl + Z` for undo,
- `Ctrl + Y` for redo,
- `Ctrl + F` for find,
- `Ctrl + S` for save,
- etc...

You'll find Tilde's default shortcuts and interface overall very intuitive.

See https://github.com/gphalkes/tilde#installing-tilde for installation instructions.

Here's how Tilde looks like.
[image: A Tilde screenshot]

Comment: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/cc46af81e544b440142f7c3ce6e49e472e6d8c733a374f483ab725ae0dbbd7b3/68747470733a2f2f6f732e6768616c6b65732e6e6c2f74696c64652f74696c64652d73637265656e73686f742e706e67

Answer (score 4):

> Have you ever been frustrated that your text editor wasn’t doing what
>   you wanted? Angered that you can’t remember...
>
> - ...how to find help?
> - ...what :wq means?
> - ...any of the little lisper
>     that you read as an undergrad?
>
> A small, brave world awaits!

While we're advocating for our favourite lightweight text editors, let me recommend the eXcellent, tiny, and fast [`xo` (exofrills)](http://exofrills.org).

It's a single Python 3 file, and it has good support for syntax highlighting through Pygments (although not perfect with non-Python):

[image]

It also has extremely simple and useful key combinations which can be readily and easily changed to your heart's content:

[image]

Other features:

> - Less than 850 lines of code in a single file!
> - Syntax highlighting!
> - Regular expression matching and replacing!
> - Search history caching!
> - WTFPL licensed!
> - Fully customizable!
> - Start at non-origin locations!
> - Hop between words on a line!
> - Jump to anywhere in the file!
> - Whole file insertion!
> - Beginner friendly - maybe you are new to words!
> - Copy and paste text!
> - Line and column status!
> - Only one row of non-text editing space!
> - Both saving & loading!

The Python3 source is [on github](https://github.com/scopatz/xo), and you can install it more easily using:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install exofrills
```

> exofrills: your text has been edited...but you are still hungry.

<sub>Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with  the exofrills project.</sub>

Comment: This looks very neat, +1 from me. Although that amount of exclamation marks is disturbing. :P

Answer (score 3):

## Mcedit

This is the (seriously underrated) built-in editor of [Midnight Commander](https://screenshots.debian.net/package/mc).
Install:

```
sudo apt install mc
```

To edit a file with it, issue

```
mcedit file-name
```

Adjustments for better usability

- Mouse support is enabled, but better disable the annoying "Persistent
  Selection" by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> and going into the `General` menu.
- Some of the default bindings are exotic, especially copy-cut-paste, but all are
  configurable via `~/.config/mc/mc.keymap` under the `[editor]` section. That file will not exist initially, so you can grab a copy from `/etc/mc/mc.keymap`.
  For your convenience, I'm appending the one I used before I switched to Vim.

  ```
  [editor]
  Store                 =  ctrl-c
  Paste                 =  ctrl-v
  Cut                   =  ctrl-x
  Undo                  =  ctrl-z
  Redo                  =  ctrl-y
  Save                  =  ctrl-s
  EditNew               =  ctrl-n
  MarkAll               =  ctrl-a
  Search                =  ctrl-f
  SearchContinue        =  ctrl-alt-f
  Help                  =  f1
  UserMenu              =  f2
  Mark                  =  f3
  Replace               =  f4
  Copy                  =  f5
  Move                  =  f6
  Options               =  f7
  Remove                =  f8
  Menu                  =  f9
  Quit                  =  f10; esc
  SyntaxOnOff           =  f11
  SaveAs                =  f12
  SyntaxChoose          =  ctrl-alt-x
  ShowNumbers           =  alt-n
  Goto                  =  alt-l
  Up                    =  up
  Down                  =  down
  Left                  =  left
  Right                 =  right
  WordLeft              =  ctrl-left
  WordRight             =  ctrl-right
  Enter                 =  enter
  Return                =  shift-enter; ctrl-enter; ctrl-shift-enter
  BackSpace             =  backspace
  Delete                =  delete
  PageUp                =  pgup
  PageDown              =  pgdn
  Home                  =  home
  End                   =  end
  Tab                   =  tab
  Top                   =  ctrl-up
  Bottom                =  ctrl-down
  TopOnScreen           =  ctrl-pgup
  BottomOnScreen        =  ctrl-pgdn
  DeleteToWordBegin     =  alt-backspace
  DeleteToWordEnd       =  alt-d
  DeleteToEnd           =  ctrl-k
  MarkPageUp            =  shift-pgup
  MarkPageDown          =  shift-pgdn
  MarkLeft              =  shift-left
  MarkRight             =  shift-right
  MarkToWordBegin       =  ctrl-shift-left
  MarkToWordEnd         =  ctrl-shift-right
  MarkUp                =  shift-up
  MarkDown              =  shift-down
  MarkToHome            =  shift-home
  MarkToEnd             =  shift-end
  MarkToFileBegin       =  ctrl-shift-home
  MarkToFileEnd         =  ctrl-shift-end
  MarkToPageBegin       =  ctrl-shift-pgup
  MarkToPageEnd         =  ctrl-shift-pgdn
  MarkScrollUp          =  ctrl-shift-up
  MarkScrollDown        =  ctrl-shift-down
  MarkColumnPageUp      =  alt-pgup
  MarkColumnPageDown    =  alt-pgdn
  MarkColumnLeft        =  alt-left
  MarkColumnRight       =  alt-right
  MarkColumnUp          =  alt-up
  MarkColumnDown        =  alt-down
  MarkColumn            =  f13
  ReplaceContinue       =  f14
  Complete              =  alt-tab
  InsertOverwrite       =  insert
  Refresh               =  ctrl-l
  Sort                  =  alt-t
  Mail                  =  alt-m
  ParagraphFormat       =  alt-p
  MatchBracket          =  alt-b
  ExternalCommand       =  alt-u
  Bookmark              =  ctrl-u
  BookmarkFlush         =  ctrl-delete
  BookmarkNext          =  ctrl-alt-down
  BookmarkPrev          =  ctrl-alt-up
  Shell                 =  ctrl-o
  InsertLiteral         =  ctrl-q
  MacroStartStopRecord  =  ctrl-r
  ShowTabTws            =  alt-underline
  ShowMargin            =  ctrl-b
  FilePrev              =  alt-minus
  FileNext              =  alt-plus
  SelectCodepage        =  alt-e
  WindowFullscreen      =  ctrl-t
  # ExtendedKeyMap           =
  # WindowPrev               =
  # WindowNext               =
  # WindowList               =
  # WindowResize             =
  # WindowMove               =
  # LearnKeys                =
  # SpellCheckSelectLang     =
  # SpellCheckCurrentWord    =
  # SpellCheck               =
  # OptionsSaveMode          =
  # RepeatStartStopRecord    =
  # Find                     =
  # InsertFile               =
  # MacroDelete              =
  # MacroStopRecord          =
  # MacroStartRecord         =
  # History                  =
  # Date                     =
  # BlockSave                =
  # MarkColumnParagraphDown  =
  # MarkColumnParagraphUp    =
  # MarkColumnScrollDown     =
  # MarkColumnScrollUp       =
  # MarkParagraphDown        =
  # MarkParagraphUp          =
  # BlockShiftRight          =
  # BlockShiftLeft           =
  # Unmark                   =
  # MarkWord                 =
  # MarkLine                 =
  # Close                    =
  # EditFile                 =
  # ParagraphDown            =
  # ParagraphUp              =
  # DeleteToHome             =
  # DeleteLine               =
  # ScrollDown               =
  # ScrollUp                 =
  ```

If you like it, update your default editor by running `select-editor`.

Comment: Yes, mcedit is a great, easy  editor. If you want a programming-enhanced version of it (e.g.: TAB-completing symbols from CTags index), you might want to checkout http://neomcedit.software

Answer (score 3):

[`micro`](https://micro-editor.github.io) seems to be right up your alley. It's a terminal editor similar to `vi` or `nano` but with much more sensible keybinds. e.g. `Ctrl+C` is copy, `Ctrl+V` is paste, `Ctrl+S` is save, `Ctrl+Q` to quit, etc. It's got built in syntax-highlighting for many languages, as well as mouse support.

If you just want to open a file, edit it, and close it, it's one of the most painless ways to do so.

Comment: cat works too!  shift-ctrl-c to copy, shift-ctrl-v to paste, ctrl-d to save and quit.

Comment: @user10489 cat doesn't have a clipboard, those are provided by your terminal emulator and aren't available in a tty.

Comment: Yup, too true.  Doesn't change the results, however.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/)

It's natural for people who are familiar with windows, and it supports [lsp](https://github.com/AndCake/micro-plugin-lsp)

There are also some rust alternatives. Though not so powerful(But faster.).

- [ox](https://github.com/curlpipe/ox)
- [smith](https://github.com/IGI-111/Smith)

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot deny that I too struggled with vi in the beginning, I think an argument can be made that vi is actually very simple to learn. (When I began using Unix the choice was either vi or emacs, so at the time I chose ed, ed being a very simple line editor, which I had learned already from reading early Unix textbooks.) I use vi daily, but I probably use only a very small subset of its features.

Here's first an argument for using vi: vi exists on all systems, uses very few resources, and may be usable over unstable and slow connections, where other editors may fail or be slow and unusable. Or in situations where the system is broken, so arrow keys are not interpreted correctly (bad terminfo settings for example.) So vi can be used to fix the configuration files leading to the problem, without being affected by the problem.

And here is how to learn a useful subset of vi:
First: stop thinking of vi as an interactive, terminal-GUI "editor", and see it as a programming language for manipulating text files. In the beginning "vi" stood for VIsual mode, and vi has a nonvisual counterpart ex, which is a good place to start.
Type ex at the shell prompt (I will use ¬ to represent return):

```
$ ex¬
Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.
:
```

Now press enter.

```
:¬
E749: empty buffer
:
```

So, lets put something in it. Type "a¬", and type a line of text, then a period on a line by itself:

```
:a¬
Hello World¬
.¬
:
```

That was the append command. Easy, short and mnemonic. But it would be nice to see what is in the buffer:

```
:%p¬
Hello World
:
```

That was the print command, p, obviously. The % is a line range shorthand. Each command may be preceded by a line number or range which the command should apply to. % means "all lines". $ means the last line, and a period means the current line. A number means that particular line. A range is written n,m and a number can be added or subtracted, so .+1,$-1 mean from the next line to the second-last line. A command consisting of just a line number goes to that line. Here is the remaining small subset of commands I use:

```
:1i¬
this text is inserted before line 1.¬
.¬
:

:w /tmp/filename¬
"/tmp/filename" [New] 2L, 49C written
:
```

w writes all (or the chosen range of) lines to a file.

```
:1d¬
```

deletes line 1.

```
:.s/Hello/Hello,/¬
Hello, World
:.s/$/!/¬
Hello, World!
```

s substitutes a regular expression. It's good to know regular expressions!

```
:q¬
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
```

q quits. wq writes and quits. q! quits without writing, and in a similar vein, w! forces a write to a file if possible.

Now a cool one:

```
:p
Hello, World!
:.!tr a-z A-Z
:p
HELLO, WORLD!
```

! as a command filters the lines into a shell command.

And finally:

```
:vi¬
```

enters VISUAL mode.
Don't be fooled. It looks like an editor, but it's still just an interactive programming shell. You just get to look at the buffer all the time, and a few more commands. In visual mode a : shows the : prompt from ex mode. The arrow keys (if they work) move around, and if they don't, then hjkl do! h left, j down, k up and l right. 0 moves to the first character and ^(think regex here!) to the first non-space character on the line. $ (regex again!) moves to the end of line. Typing :999¬ goes to line 999, naturally, just like in ex mode.

"i" enters insert mode, which now inserts on characters instead of lines, and ends with pressing escape instead of ".¬". "I" inserts at the beginning, "a" after the character under the cursor, and "A" after the end of the current line. Always press escape when done typing text. "x" deletes the character under the cursor, and "D" deletes from the cursor to end of line. "Y" yanks (copies) the current line, and "P" pastes it back. ":pu" does the same, but can be preceded by a line number. ":ya" is the ex equivalent of "Y", and again, useful to apply to a line range. I think there is a mark command as well, but I will admit I don't remember it. I don't miss it.

The above is what I use, and I know I am probably not a very "efficient" vi user. On the other hand, I do use ex's versatility, for example to script editing configuration files. Need to change your hostname foo.bar.com to www.foobar.com in a number of conf files?

```
for file in conf/*
do (echo "%s/foo.bar.com/www.foobar.com/" ; echo "wq") |ex $file ; done
```

What I am trying to say is, that I think the problem with vi is that people think of it as a difficult editor. All it takes is to change your mindset a little, and view it as a very simple yet also very powerful interactive programming language instead. So powerful that even with a subset of the available commands, you can use it to great effect - not just as an editor but as a general, scriptable tool well integrated with the rest of Unix. I doubt nano would do all of this - emacs...maybe.

Comment: Sorry but... this does not answer the question. OP asked for an alternative to vim and answers should provide that.

Comment: I commend the work you put into this answer, but it doesn't really answer the question -- a tutorial on and plug for vim does not belong here at all, but it does belong on your blog.

Comment: This answer is exactly why so many people are asking for an alternative to the viemacs - the more we say they're unpleasant to use, the more the converted insist that we try harder to use them.