# Why was the nano that was installed manually not colored?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, make, tar, nano

I recently installed Nano manually.
I downloaded and installed the latest version from the site:
[This one](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.2.tar.gz)
and
[this one](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v5/nano-5.8.tar.gz)

I installed both (ncrurses 6.2 and nano 5.8) with commands:

```
mkdir /tmp/myfiles
cd /tmp/myfiles
tar zxvf ... for ncrurses
tar -zxvf ... for nano
./configure
make
make install
```

Although it was installed, it was not colored (And in the end I did not find a way to remove it too، And I used the nuclear option).

Why was the nano that was installed manually not colored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe nano is B/W by default. You can set the colors in `/etc/nanorc`, like this:

```
## Paint the interface elements of nano.
## These are examples; by default there are no colors.
set titlecolor black,green
set statuscolor black,yellow
# set selectedcolor brightwhite,magenta
set numbercolor yellow
set keycolor cyan
set functioncolor white
```

However, syntax highlighting should be colored by default. [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90013/how-do-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-nano) has information about syntax highlighting in nano - check if the directory `/usr/share/nano/` is in fact included in your nanorc file:

```
include /usr/share/nano/*.nanorc
```

In addition, for the syntax highlighting to take effect, the file must either have the correct extension, or the correct shebang (`#!`) in the beginning.

Comment: The codes were similar to the way you look with ```cat```.