# Opening a file in read-only mode using nano

Tags: read-only, nano

I am new to Ubuntu. I know I can open a file using vim in read-only mode by pass the `-R` option:

```
vim -R <filename> //Gives warning if I try to write
```

However, if I do the same thing with nano, I am able to write files freely:

```
nano -R <filename>  //I can still write
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I open files in read-only mode using nano?

Comment: If you're only wanting to view a file, why not use cat? For example: `cat <filename>`

Comment: @linux4me a text editor allows scrolling, searching through text, syntax highlighting, a familiar interface, and other conveniences that 'cat' doesn't provide.

Comment: Seems like you are assuming that `-R` has a constant OS-defined or OS-enforced meaning. That's not a valid assumption. `-R` and similar flags are defined by each application. That's what happens when you have a thousand different developers and a thousand independent software projects. Ubuntu is a merely *distributor* ("distro") of upstream Open Source and Free Software projects, and cannot impose a standard upon them.

Comment: @linux4me: `less -iM <filename>` would be my preference.  I use `alias m=less` with `LESS = iMRj5X` in my `~/.lesskey`.  Along with `,` and `.` as prev-file and next-file.  Viewing files or piping into a pager is so common I want a 1-letter alias for it.  (And `m` for `more` or `less` is fun, and keeps it on a different letter than `ls` or `l`.)

Comment: @Esther: Does `nano` have syntax highlighting?  `less` has all the other things you mentioned, being designed for viewing text files, with space for page-down since it's not an editor.

Comment: @PeterCordes it can, if you configure it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/90013/how-do-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-nano

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nano does not use '-R' as a "read-only-" option and uses '-R' for [something](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nano) else.

> -R, --restricted
>
> Restricted  mode:  don't read or write to any file not specified
> on the command line.  This means: don't read  or  write  history
> files; don't allow suspending; don't allow spell checking; don't
> allow a file to be appended to, prepended to, or saved  under  a
> different  name  if  it  already  has one; and don't make backup
> files.  Restricted mode can also be activated by  invoking  nano
> with any name beginning with 'r' (e.g. "rnano").

it uses `-v` or `--view`:

> -v, --view
>
> Just view the file and disallow editing: read-only  mode.   This
> mode  allows  the user to open also other files for viewing, un‐
> less --restricted is given too.