# Python GTK 3 IDE

Tags: gnome, application-development, gtk3

Is there any available IDE for Python GTK 3, 
i.e. An IDE which give the programmer an auto complete feature with method Description etc.?

Comment: Please, see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu. Most of the IDEs listed there have good python support. Personally, I use PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [IDLE 3](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/idle-python3.1/)

```
sudo apt-get install idle3 idle-python3.2
```

another one [bypython](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bpython/)

You might want to take a look at available tools

[Ubuntu community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Programming)

[Power Users Programming](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerUsersProgramming)

Answer (score 0):

Also I like geney, it is in software center and is beginner friendly.
Also there is codeblocks which  is pretty good.
And I saw a new one called spider the other day whitch has got some very good reviews.
Python is well supported in Ubuntu so have a search in software center theres about 20 IDE s with python support just play around till you find one you like...

Answer (score 0):

Try Anjuta IDE if you want a graphical designer

```
sudo apt-get install anjuta anjuta-extras
```

Or try PyCharm [jetbrains.com/pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm) if you want a smart full-featured IDE ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) installed. You can install VSCode by downloading the .deb installer and running in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install /path/to/vscode.deb
```

Then, run VSCode, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to launch *VSCode Quick Open*, paste the following and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to install the Python extension:

```
ext install ms-python.python
```

---

Another Python IDE I am using and recommend is [Jupyter Lab](https://jupyter.org/index.html). If you are using the [Anaconda Python Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) you can install it by running:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

If not, you can install it using `pip`:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```