# What are the best Python IDEs?

Tags: python, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

What are some of the best Python IDEs for Ubuntu 12.04?
Would you benefit from me learning Python?

Comment: Here's an extensive list of available IDEs/Editors for Python http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Bluegriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) and its many extensions?

Comment: For Python beginners I recommend Thonny (http://thonny.org)

Comment: Pycharm is the best! You can get it free fro Ubuntu right now!

Answer (score 12):

If you want a professional IDE but not free, then you can buy [Wingware](http://www.wingware.com/wingide/features).

In contrary, if you want a free professional IDE, then try [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/index.html). The version 4 is for Python 2, and the version 5 is for Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

Because this greatly varies from person to person, I recommend you just try out a few and find one you like. I am currently working with Eclipse + PyDev. (PyDev is an Eclipse plugin.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) editor, you can add some scripts like [python.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790) to make it support Python more professionally.

If you prefer working in IDE like Eclipse, then [PyDev](http://pydev.org) will be suitable for you.

By the way, using Python's interactive command line terminal is a good way to start learning Python.

Comment: `bpython` is an even better version of the python command line interpreter (it has tab completion, inline help and syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this [Creative Commons licensed](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)  e-book : [A byte of Python](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python/) to begin learning.

IMHO Best for beginners and also you will see [suggestions for editors.](http://python.swaroopch.com/first_steps.html#choosing-an-editor)

Here is a list of [Unix-Only editors](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors#Unix-Only_Editors) if you want to take a look.

I suggest to begin with gedit or geany in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using eclipse with PyDev. It is a straight forward solution. You can get more informations in the following link http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html