# Using Visual Studio for Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

I would like to make programs in C++ for Ubuntu and Windows. I will be using visual studio on a Windows PC for the programming. I know how to make the install files for Windows.

I just need to know how to make the files Linux uses for programs in Visual Studio?

If you don't know visual studio could some one tell be the extensions used on install files or runnable executable(for Linux).

Comment: Visual Studio is a Windows thing. Don't bother setting that up on Ubuntu. You might be interested in cross-platform programming using Qt C++ or other options...

Comment: It's not exactly the same question, but recent VS is a no-go on linux.  Use VS proper in VBox for Windows only apps or any number of cross-platform toolkits listed in the What IDEs are available question.  Notably: Qt, Code::blocks, and Eclipse CDT.

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing Re-read the q; I think his issue is broader than just an IDE.

Comment: @gertvdijk Agreed.  I thought it was the most helpful response to "cross-platform C++" as far as variety in answers.

Comment: @WorkAround: I think you are missing an important point. With Visual Studio you won't be programming in **[C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)**, but in **[Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B)**. If you want to make your applications cross-platform (i.e. without using Wine or virtualization technologies), you will need a **Visual C++** compiler. Before looking for an _IDE_, you should first look for the _compiler_ (if exists).

Answer (score 1):

I have had some experience in cross platform programming. To begin with Visual Studio, code built on visual studio will not run inherently as the binaries compiled from Visual Studio wont be supported. You might try to develop in C# using Visual studio and then can use mono libraries to run that code on linux but wont recommend it at all. Another way would be to use gcc and compile ur code using mingw of cygwin on windows and use that compiled code on  windows and use gcc compiler to get binaries in linux. As for ide which is available for both the operating systems I would suggest Eclipse.

But if you want a good suggestion for cross platform development, then you should focus on all the operating systems independently as each have major differences.

Further with respect to qt, they again use mingw/cygwin (for windows) and generic linux libraries so you can consider them too (they give some good functional libraries too). Its just depends on what you are building!

Answer (score 1):

Visual c++ is not cross platform, If you prefer cross platform application creation from visual studio try qt plugin for visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Or look at the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/junosr1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.