# C++ Compiler Program IDE

Tags: software-recommendation, programming, c++, c, ide

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my old laptop and I want to start working on it.
Is there any program like Visual Studio for Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: We have a general topic for this kind of question and you can find it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have limited experience with Visual Studio, but when working on Linux I've always used the IDE, Eclipse.

The IDE is highly modular, you can find all sorts of plugins that will help make development for different platforms easier.

The IDE with "C++ plugin" can be found [hare](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/junosr2) - Simplest to download directly and unzip.

Comment: Thanks! Where do I need to put the extracted folder?

Comment: Totally up to you. Simply unzip and run.