# Where to write java programs on ubuntu?

Tags: java, jdk

I want on write java programs on ubuntu. I have java on my windows OS and I write programs in Notepad++ and compile and run it in command prompt. I installed java on ubuntu. What should I use to write programs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `emacs`, `gedit` etc to write your java code and compile in terminal, if you wish to use IDE for java you can use `eclipse` or `netbeans`.

The list of editors is really very long. See [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu) to know more.

Comment: Thank you for the list. Which of those do you suggest for beginners? It should have good formatting like notepad++.        http://encosia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/notepad++-js.png

Answer (score 1):

Most people use Netbeans or Eclipse to write Java code.