# Geany symbol menu in VIM

Tags: vim, geany, vi

On the Geany editor there is symbol tab which when you pass one C program to Geany it shows all functions and classes and variables and macros in the list . So is there any ability like that in VIM? If you have no the idea about symbol in the Geany look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu).

Comment: Since vim is an extremely extensible language see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Vim_like_an_IDE#Code_Browsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you are searching for is called Outline in Eclipse, Navigator in Netbeans and Source Code Browser in Gedit.
A common program that creates this tree is CTAGS. The most common used is exuberant CTAGS http://ctags.sourceforge.net/. It does support 41 languages including C.

Here a tutorial how to combine it with vim:
http://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags
or some tips and tricks on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks

Comment: Much easier to use the Tagbar or Tag List addons mentioned by kraxor.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/) plugin. Or [Tag List](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/), which is a bit older and less maintained I think.

Comment: Tag list is well maintained - does not need many updates as generally works so well.