# Best IDE for php/web developement in Ubuntu

Tags: php, netbeans, aptana-studio

Can anyone suggest an IDE for php development in ubuntu 14.04.

In Netbeans fonts looks narrow and ugly. Is there anyother alternative ?

What about Aptana Studio 3 ?

Comment: You should also check this => http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/five-cross-platform-editors-for-web-developers

Comment: And this => http://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu

Comment: I've always loved eclipse. it's a great IDE and allows me do alot of stuff.  go for kepler 4.3

Comment: I just use *vim* and terminal windows.  I should get around to learning *screen* one day.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into learning VIM. I've been doing PHP for 15 years now, and VIM takes the cake out of all the other IDE's or editors I've used. It's a bit of a learning curve, but the beauty is that you can install it on almost any OS. Secondly, because it's a terminal client, it helps to login to remote servers to edit files. Lastly, there is also a graphical version (gvim) if you prefer, but uses the same basic interface and command syntax. VIM is very powerful, but it's power is mostly hidden from the get go. Take a look at http://www.koch.ro/blog/index.php?/archives/63-VIM-as-a-PHP-IDE.html to see what I mean. Good luck.