# Image processing on opencv c++ tool suggestion

Tags: software-recommendation, c++, ide, opencv, image-processing

I'm starting Digital Image Processing with opencv and c++.

**What would be the best application for image processing with opencv c++?**

Please give me suggestion on that.

**Research**:

I do some research on this. I know that

```
g++ program.cpp -o program `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

will execute an opencv c++ code. But I want an application that will do like on *windows* we use *visual studio* for this.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You seem to be asking [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks. I asked for which one is the _easiest_ and _best_ for digital image processing with opencv c++.

Answer (score 0):

OK, no one has any interested in this topic, so, I get into Internet past hole day and I've found some-thing that could be useful.

On windows we have *Visual Studio* where it is very easy to do image processing. But on any Linux system we don't have that. But here **CodeBlocks** comes in handy.

let's do this with some steps.

**Step 1:** Install *OpenCV* whatever version you like.

**Step 2:** Install *CodeBlocks* whatever version you like.

**Step 3:** Open *CodeBlocks* and create an *OpenCV* project

[image: *Creating an OpenCV Project*]

**Step 4:** After creating the project go to `Project` >> `Build Options`

[image: *Project Build option*]

**Step 5:** On this window,go to `compiler settings` >> `Other options`

Here you will see `-s` on the box. Type this under `-s`(like picture)

```
`pkg-config --cflags opencv`
```

[image: *Setting the compiler*]

**Step 6:** Now go to `Linker settings` >> `Other Linker Options`

On the blank box copy these line and click **OK**

```
`pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

[image: *Setting Linker options*]

Now Build and Run the project. It should run.

**Reference:**  [*OpenCV on Code::Blocks , ubuntu 14.04*](https://youtu.be/dxf3WPg8gKk)