# I need a lightweight IDE for C coding, for Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, c, ide

I have no clue about linux, i've used Windows all my life. I recently installed Lubuntu to a really old laptop i had no use of. I need to install a lightweigh IDE for C coding to use for my university needs. I've only worked with Dev C++ and Visual Studio in my main computer that is able to handle these software. But i need to get a working IDE on my laptop that just works for me to code on the way. 
Some info about my laptop:
Laptop : Acer extensa 5230
CPU : Intel Celeron 2Ghz Single Core 32bit
RAM : 1GB ddr2
Storage : 160GB 
Thanks for the help in advance. 
PS : Any advice for starting on linux would be very helpful.

Comment: Related: [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

Comment: You didn't specify what Lubuntu you are using.  Legacy Lubuntu uses LXDE (thus has GTK+2 libs in memory) so may lead to a different choice to modern Lubuntu (LXQt) which is Qt(5) based.  Thus if you want to be lightweight, this **should** be taken into account otherwise you're wasting RAM as multiple libs doing the same thing need to share memory at the same time.  You did mention x86/32-bit so it's likely Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (using older GTK+2)

Comment: Very lightweight system for programming. Some more info here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2416855

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeLite is a powerful and lightweight IDE specializing in C, C++, PHP and JavaScript. Its features include:

- Generic support for compilers (for example Clang)
- Built-in GDB support
- Database-based code completion mechanism
- Syntax highlighting for C/C++, Java, Perl, XML, Makefile, Lua, Diff files,
  PHP, JavaScript, Python, HTML, and ASP
- Text folding
- Bookmarks
- Find and Replace
- doxygen comment generator

To install CodeLite in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal type:

```
sudo apt install codelite
```

[image: CodeLite]